# Easiest way to serve a webpage from laptop and test on smartphone

Tags: webserver

I'm developing a webpage, and I'd like to test it on a real mobile browser. I have the local html file, what's the simplest way I can access it and interact with it on my phone?

Ideally I'd like to "set and forget", so I can just type an address in my browser phone, and if I'm on the same network as my work computer, it'll load the HTML.

Comment: Setup a web server?  As-is, this is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a webserver on your laptop.  You use the local private IP address of your laptop on your phone's browser to connect when they are both on the same network.